How to set manifest_storage for ManifestFilesMixin (Django)
I use django-storages to serve my static files from S3. I want to use the ManifestFilesMixin for cache busting my CSS and JS files.
The following works fine:
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class ManifestS3Storage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    pass

Except that staticfiles.json is placed in my S3 bucket. I don't want this as explained here.
The Django docs mention that it is possible to give a "manifest_storage" argument to the ManifestFilesMixin but I don't know how to do this. The docs mention how to do it for the ManifestStaticFilesStorage class but I don't understand how to do this for the ManifestFilesMixin.
